# asp.net C# reload already opened popup window button using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

I have button that open a pop up window by clicking a button in (page 1) which will open (page 2),
and it works fine but I want when I click the popup button again I want to reload or refresh the already opened window (page 2) the problem is when I click the button again it reload the current page (page1)

java script:

```
   function openPopUp() {

       var  x = window.open('emp_search.aspx', 'My popUp', 'width=570,height=290,left=500,right=300,menubar=No,status=no,location=yes,toolbar=No,scrollbars=No,location =No', ''); //open popup window

 x = window.opener.location.reload(); //reload the already opened popup window

        return false;

     }
```

button:

```
        <button type="button" onclick="openPopUp();" >Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: `x` is the window due to `window.open()`. So `x.location.reload()`. However, you have to store `x` differently. Also be aware of [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by using x.focus();

instead of  x = window.opener.location.reload();